# Shell script to copy specific files in directory using loops

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm trying to copy only specific files from a  directory which has n number of files? Can I try that using loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Unix/Linux as you asked for a shell script

```
cd somedir
for F in *.dat
do
   echo about to copy $F
   cp $F /home/backup
done
```

would copy all files in `somedir` that ended in `.dat` to the directory `/home/backup`